# Showing that a given subset is an ideal of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $\Bbb Z[x]$ be the set of polynomials in indeterminate $x$ with integer coefficients. Consider the subset $I = \{ 2f(x) + xg(x) | f(x), g(x) ∈ \Bbb Z[x] \}$. Show that $I$ is an ideal in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

I'm having a bit of trouble getting this started.

Comment: What is the exact nature of the trouble? Try to use definition. You have posted some other problems also where you have asked for help with definition. I would suggest you to read a good book in case you are having trouble with definitions.

Comment: I don't know how to apply the definition of an ideal here. If I have some $a \in I$ and some $b \in \Bbb Z[x]$ then I need to show that $ab, ba \in I$. I apologize. My university uses an in house textbook  that just lists the definitions. There are very few proofs or examples and my professor tends to jump around in the textbook. The semester has been rather difficult because of the sporadic nature of the the lesson plan. @Anurag A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check that I satisfies the definition of an ideal. This means I needs to be a subgroup of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$[x], which is closed under left and right multiplication by elements $p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}$[x].

To show that I is indeed a subgroup it is enough to show it is closed under multiplication and subtraction. Suppose $p(x),q(x)\in I$ then:
$$p(x)=2f_1(x)+xg_1(x)\tag{1}$$ $$q(x)=2f_2(x)+xg_2(x)\tag{2}$$ with $f_i,g_j\in \mathbb{Z}$[x]. Hence, $$p(x)-q(x)=2(f_1(x)-f_2(x))+x(g_1(x)-g_2(x))\tag{3}$$Since $\mathbb{Z}$[x] is closed under subtraction the difference is in I. You also need to show I is closed under multiplication f,but this is not bad either. Since $q(x)\in I\subset \mathbb{Z[x]}$ we have $$p(x)q(x)=2f_1(x)q(x)+xg_1(x)q(x)\tag{4}$$ where again this has the desired form since $\mathbb{Z[x]}$ is a ring($f_1(x)q(x)\in \mathbb{Z[x]}$ etc..) . So I is a subgroup of the ring. Notice we've only shown I is closed under multiplication between elements in I. To show that it is an ideal we also have to show that for 
$f(x)\in\mathbb{Z[x]}$ and $p(x)\in I$ that $p(x)f(x)\in I$ and $f(x)p(x)\in I$. I will leave this last part to you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I showed the part that you left for me. I didn't know I had to show that $I$ was a subgroup too.

Comment: In the context of a problem/hw assignment it will typically be a given that it is a subgroup,however it is part of the definition of an ideal. Ideals will serve the a similar purpose as normal subgroups do in group theory. Just like normal subgroups are subgroups with added structure, ideals are subrings with added structure.

Comment: I think saw subset and just read it as subgroup in my head and didn't even think about needing to prove it. When you say added structure, do you mean that like a ring, a subgroup of a ring will be closed under both operations? I'm a little confused about what your last sentence means.

Comment: No I meant the ideal has the added structure of being closed under multiplication with all elements of the ring,not just I itself. This condition is independent of it being a subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

Someone recently commented in another thread that whenever we have an ideal of a ring, it can be profitable to determine which homomorphism has this ideal as its kernel.  In this case, we can use this interpretation to show that the set $I$ in your question is an ideal.

Define
\begin{align*}
\varphi: \mathbb{Z}[x] &\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\\
f(x) &\mapsto \overline{f(0)}
\end{align*}
where the bar indicates the remainder mod $2$.  One can show that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism (indeed, it is the composition of the evaluation homomorphism $f(x) \mapsto f(0)$ and the quotient map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$) and that its kernel is the set $I$ in your question.  Since the kernel of a homomorphism is always an ideal, this shows that $I$ is an ideal.