# Show Ideal $\{ pa_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots + a_nx^n:a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\}\ $ of Z[x] is a maximal where p is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let p be prime. Let $I = \{ pa_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots + a_nx^n:a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\} $. Prove it is a maximal.

---

Some elements of I are $$\{ p1,p2,\dots p1+x+p2+2x,p2+x^2+1,\dots \}$$
$Z[x]/I=\{0,1,2,\dots,p-1\} $ it is $Z_p$ which is a field

For example consider $x^3+2x$ $x\in I$ So $x+I=0+I$
Now, using

> R communitive ring with unity and let A be an ideal of R then R/A is a field iff A is maximal

So $I$ is a maximal of Z[x].

---

Was able to prove it was an Ideal to myself. Not sure 100% that what I have above  is correct. either way I am interested in doing it by contradiction from definition of maximal

> A maximal Ideal A of R is a proper of R if, whenever B is an ideal of R and $A \subseteq B\subseteq R$ then $B=A \vee B=R$

This is kind of extra but is it a principal Ideal? From previous question Every ideal in a field is a principal.

Comment: *Hint*: Consider the evaluation map $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}$, $f(x) \mapsto f(0)$, composed with the quotient map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.  Can you show $I$ is the kernel of this map?  Since the image is a field, what does that say about $I$?

Comment: Also, here's [a relevant link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563727/showing-that-a-given-subset-is-an-ideal-of-a-polynomial-ring/1563832#1563832).

Comment: @SpamIAm Maximal!!!  I'll take a look at that link closely.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For easier notation, we can write $I = (p,X)$, since it is the smallest ideal of $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]$ containing the integer $p$ and the indeterminate $X$.

The most direct way (in my opinion) of rigorously showing that $I$ is an ideal, in fact a maximal ideal, is to consider the ring homomorphism $\pi: \mathbb{Z}[X]\to\mathbb{Z}/p$ sending $X$ to $0$.  Since $\pi$ is surjective, its kernel is a maximal ideal.  But it is straightforward to show that $I=\ker{\pi}$.

This is conceptually identical to your proof, but may be easier to make 100% rigorous.

---

As for going directly from the definition: suppose that $I \subset J \subset R$, where $J$ is an ideal.  If $I\neq J$, then there is some $f(X)\in J$, $f(X)\notin I$.

Write $f(x) = a+Xg(X)$.  Since $a$ is not divisible by $p$, there are integers $k,l$ such that $ak + pl = 1$, by Bézout (here we mimic the usual proof that $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is a field).

Then $k(f(X)-Xg(X))+pl=1$, so $kf(X) + pl - kXg(X) = 1$.  But $f(X)$, $p$, and $X$ all lie in $J$, so the left-hand side lies in $J$, hence $1\in J$, so $J=R$.

---

You are correct that $I=(p,X)$ is not a principal ideal.  Indeed, if $I = (t)$, then $t$ is a factor of both $X$ and $p$, and the only possibilities are $t=\pm 1$, which implies $I=R$, a contradiction.